# YII2 - Column filter in index.php won't work

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I've modified the index.php to show name instead the id's.

This is my orders/index.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use frontend\models\Statuses;


$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Ordini');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
$user = Yii::$app->user->identity;
?>
<div class="orders-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?php 
            if ($user->role == 10 || $user->role > 40)
                echo Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Nuovo'), ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']);
        ?>
    </p>
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>   

 <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            ['attribute'=>'customer_id', 'value'=>'CustomersName',],
            ['attribute'=>'product_id', 'value'=>'ProductsName',],
             'date',
             [
                 'attribute'=>'status_id', 
                 'value'=>'StatusesName',
                 'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'status_id', ArrayHelper::map(Statuses::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name'),['class'=>'form-control','prompt' => 'Select Category']),
             ],

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?></div>
```

Filter doesn't work. I've tryed with dropdown or only number with no success.
I don't know how to check where it fail!

In OrdersSearch? In the model or controller?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to provide the whole code for the dropdown field. This should be enough:

```
'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Statuses::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
```

Comment: Add the code for the class behind `$searchModel` in your question.

Comment: OrdersSearch do you mean? Here oders  http://pastebin.com/VLLzXf8c   and here ordersearch  http://pastebin.com/pSd64qmC

Comment: Does it work when you extract `status_id` filter to separate chained method in `OrdersSearch` like `->andFilterWhere(['status_id' => $this->status_id])`